# how to add windows phone emulator to the uwp project

Tags: windows, mobile, uwp, windows-phone-8-emulator

Now I'm updating someone's UWP project.
I use **Visual Studio 2017** on **windows 10 64bit**.
Building is successful.
But When I run this project, I got an error.

> DEP6200: Bootstrapping failed.Device cannot be found.
>   SmartDeviceException - Deployment failed because no device was
>   detected.

I think, the reason is that I didn't use real windows phone.
So that I wanted to use **windows phone emulator**.
But I don't know `how to add emulator to running option`.
When I created new `UWP project`, I could find emulators which are connect to that project.

Anyone solved this issue?

Comment: Do you want to run it on phone, or you just want to run it? If the latter, you can just change the target to "Local Machine" and the architecture to x64 (or x86) and run the UWP on your desktop directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install Emulators.
Please take a look at this page and download them [Windows Emulator archive](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive) .

Simply choose your emulator version that you want to debug your app and then Click **INSTALL EMULATOR** , After installation Restart Visual Studio .
[image: How to debug app on installed Emulator]

Answer (score 0):

To use emulator there are some prerequest, you can check it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/test-with-the-emulator).

That's to say, first ,you need to make sure you followed the system requirements.

Then you have to install emulator like MKH said. And at last, set the CPU to ARM and choose the emulator you need, run the project and you will see the result.